# Uninstall SQL Server 2005 Express after Demoting the DC

Tags: sql-server

A Windows Server 2003 SP2 hosting a now orphan installation of SQL 2005 Workgroup was pressed into service as a DC in a disaster recovery scenario. It has since been demoted. The server also hosts legacy apps for which we lack reinstallation resources; thus our desire to preserve it as close to intact as possible while removing the orphaned roles.
All efforts to remove SQL 2005 thru Control Panel and ARPWrapper /remove fail with error 29528.

Should I abandon this and leave the orphan SQL dormant, or is it reasonable to remove it post-demote?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
To work around this problem, follow these steps:
Start Registry Editor, and then locate one of the following registry subkeys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2005\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\Setup


Note Only one of these registry subkeys will exist on your computer.
Empty the following registry entries:
SQLGroup
FTSGroup
AGTGroup
Exit Registry Editor.
Uninstall SQL Server 2005 or install SQL Server 2005 SP1.
```

Mentions it's for SP1, but worth a try.  Excerpt taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919945

Comment: Here's another similar article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925976.  This one specifically includes Express.